# The proper way to implement paging in SqlDataReader !

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I Am correctly using my own way to achieve this, but I  don't know if it is efficient or not , so this is the function :

```
public SqlDataReader GetArticlesByPage(int pageNum, int pageSize)
{
    if (pageNum == 0)
        pageNum = 1;
    SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(string.Format("SELECT TOP {0} Des, Id, Title, Icon FROM Threads ORDER BY Id DESC", pageSize * pageNum));
    int div = pageNum - 1;
    div = pageSize * div;
    for (int i = 0; i < div; i++)
        dr.Read();
    return dr;
}
```

It works fine but as you see the code, when I need to take the articles of page 10 when the page size e.g 10 per page I select the top 10*10 result then skip the unwanted results by using FOR statement . 
Any suggestions , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 8):

You can do all the paging at sql server.

For example, see

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2005/11/18/1323.aspx

If you don't want to do it this way and insist on using `TOP`, then skipping the rows at start is pretty all you can do and it's ok.

(from above link)

```
DECLARE @PageNum AS INT;
DECLARE @PageSize AS INT;
SET @PageNum = 2;
SET @PageSize = 10;

WITH OrdersRN AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderID) AS RowNum
          ,OrderID
          ,OrderDate
          ,CustomerID
          ,EmployeeID
      FROM dbo.Orders
)

SELECT * 
  FROM OrdersRN
 WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 
                  AND @PageNum * @PageSize
 ORDER BY OrderDate
         ,OrderID;
```

Comment: Wow, I'd always done this using OFFSET FETCH. I ran a test to compare that method with this one, and the CTE is much much more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 then you can use the built in  Common table Expressions and ROW_NUMBER() function to achieve this very easily and efficiently.

You will write your query as

```
WITH MAINSQL AS(

SELECT Des, Id, Title, Icon,
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id desc)
 FROM Threads 
)
SELECT * FROM MAINSQL WHERE rownum between 10 AND 100
```

Replace 10 and 100 by the starting and ending row of your page

For more information see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

And

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Hope this helps